# In Gtk, how do I make a Button with just a stock icon?

Tags: c#, gtk, gtk#

I want to create a button with the stock "Remove" icon on it, but without the text "Remove". If I use `Button button = new Button(Stock.Remove);`, I get the opposite: just the text, and no icon. I will have many of these buttons, and the text makes it look cluttered. How do I get just the icon?

Note: these are regular buttons, not toolbar buttons.

Edit:
This is how it currently looks:

[image: cluttered]

I want to replace these buttons with small, unobtrusive, icon-only buttons.

Answer (score 6, accepted):

First create a stock [`Gtk.Image`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=C:Gtk.Image(System.String,Gtk.IconSize)), and then create your [`Gtk.Button`](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/index.aspx?link=C:Gtk.Button(Gtk.Widget)), passing the image as its argument.

```
Image image = new Image(Stock.Remove, IconSize.Button);
Button button = new Button(image);
```

Comment: Thanks, this works with one tweak: You have to do "new Image(Stock.Remove, IconSize.Button)". If you just pass it Stock.Remove, it seems to use the wrong overload and can't find the image.

Answer (score 1):

See the list of [GTK+ stock images](http://www.go-mono.com/docs/monodoc.ashx?link=T%3aGtk.Stock). Then just use one of those identifiers in your call to create the button, there is absolutely no need to manually create an Image yourself:

```
Button remove = Button.NewFromStock(Stock.Remove);
```

I consider this way cleaner than having to "know" and deal with the proper image size hint.

**UPDATE:** At the time of writing, the Mono link doesn't actually work. Here is the [list of stock items](http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Stock-Items.html) and the `gtk_button_new_from_stock()` function description, from the core GTK+ C documentation. The GTK# wrapping done in Mono seems to follow the original pretty closely.

Comment: Is it the link that is wrong, or has their site crashed? I get Server Error 500 from that GTK+ stock images link of yours...

Comment: Swish: I think it's the latter, their site seems to have problems. Perhaps I should have said so in the post, but that seemed too transient. :)

Comment: this doesn't create icon-only buttons though, right?  so it doesn't address the question?  in fact, it does exactly what the OP's code does, only more verbose?

Comment: http://library.gnome.org/devel/gtk/stable/gtk-Stock-Items.html returns 404 now too.