# Stock Icons not shown on buttons

Tags: python, gtk, pygtk

```
self.button = gtk.Button(stock=gtk.STOCK_DELETE)
```

Only Shows:
Delete

Comment: This answer might help you: http://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734914/in-gtk-how-do-i-make-a-button-with-just-a-stock-icon

Answer (score 11, accepted):

This is a recent change in GTK - the developers wanted icons not to appear on buttons. On Linux, this can be changed by editing the `gconf` key

```
/desktop/gnome/interface/buttons_have_icons
```

On windows, I think (I haven't actually tried this) that you need to set a value in your gtkrc file (for me it's in `C:\Program Files\Gtk+\etc\gtkrc`) and use a theme that supports icons (I think the default one doesn't).

You can also add `gtk-button-images = 1` to your `~/.gtkrc-2.0` file *after* setting the theme which may over ride the option from `gconf`.

**EDIT** in answer to your comment:

Just like this answer, but in Python: [In Gtk, how do I make a Button with just a stock icon?](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/1734914/in-gtk-how-do-i-make-a-button-with-just-a-stock-icon/1735265#1735265)

For python, it's just

```
image = gtk.Image()
#  (from http://www.pygtk.org/docs/pygtk/gtk-stock-items.html)
image.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_**)
button = gtk.Button()
button.set_image(image)
button.set_label("")
```

Comment: Thanks for the prompt answer. Do you happen to know how to remove the text portion of icons from buttons?

Comment: I answered your comment in the edit - it's basically like the question Trent posted in the comment to your original question.

Comment: @DanielG What is the value you need to change in Windows?

Answer (score 14):

The Python equivalent for setting the property without having to change any system config files is:

```
settings = gtk.settings_get_default()
settings.props.gtk_button_images = True
```

This should follow a call to window.show() and, obviously, precede the gtk.main() loop.

Comment: If anyone's looking to do this in C, `GtkSettings *settings = gtk_settings_get_default(); g_object_set(settings, "gtk-button-images", TRUE, NULL);` is the equivalent procedure.

Answer (score 2):

I had to do this to get it to work from Python without changing my config file. When I called set_image(), no image was being displayed.

```
image = gtk.Image()
image.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_**, gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON)
button = gtk.Button()
button.add(image)
button.show()
```

Answer (score 2):

If you work with pygobject, the new syntax is:

```
image.set_from_stock(gtk.STOCK_**, Gtk.IconSize.BUTTON)
```

Comment: I had to use gtk.ICON_SIZE_BUTTON

Answer (score 1):

I had the same issue in GTKmm on Windows. The "MS-Windows" theme disables images on stock buttons and the theme has priority over settings in gtkrc (so putting gtk-button-images = true in gtkrc didn't help). What I did is to modify the GTK settings runtime, and the images appeared as expected. :) Here's the code in C++:

```
Glib::RefPtr<Gtk::Settings> settings = Gtk::Settings::get_default();
/* force using icons on stock buttons: */
settings->property_gtk_button_images() = true;
```

It should be placed after the first window is constructed.

Answer (score 0):

in Gtk3 `gtk.STOCK` method has been [deprecated from v3.10](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#Gtk.Button.new_from_stock).

> Deprecated since version 3.10: Use Gtk.Button.new_with_label ()
>   instead.

In the case it doesn't help since it points to the custom label solution (`new_with_label`) If you want to use STOCK stuff you still can do so with new methods `Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name(icon_name, size)` and `Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic(label)` which will create new buttons with stock icon and label respectively.

Example new button with a "stock" **icon**:

```
button = Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name ("edit-paste", Gtk.IconSize.SMALL_TOOLBAR)
```

Example new button with a "stock" **label**:

```
button = Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic("_Open")
```

NOTE: on serious code creating a constant variable instead of using the string straight is a better option :)

References:

- [Gtk.Button](https://developer.gnome.org/gtk3/stable/GtkButton.html)
- [static new_with_mnemonic(label)](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#Gtk.Button.new_with_mnemonic)
- [new_from_icon_name(icon_name, size)](http://lazka.github.io/pgi-docs/Gtk-3.0/classes/Button.html#Gtk.Button.new_from_icon_name)
- [Freedesktops Naming Convention](http://standards.freedesktop.org/icon-naming-spec/icon-naming-spec-latest.html)

Answer (score -1):

You can show explicitly the button image, justly, Gtk+ developers do not recommend doing this because it's overrides the Gtk+ user configuration.

So...

```
button.get_image().show()
```