# Image shows up in Glade designer but not when previewing

Tags: image, gtk, gtk3, glade

I'm using Glade to design a GUI for my program and I wanted to add a custom icon to a button.

So, I created the button, set **Button Content** to *Label with optional image*. Then, I created an GtkImage widget and set the button to use that image:

[image]

Now, the image shows up fine in Glade's designer:

[image]

but not in the preview:

[image]

It just shows the missing resource icon.

I looked [at this question on Ask Ubuntu](https://askubuntu.com/questions/154938/how-do-i-get-images-to-appear-on-buttons-in-glade-designer) and [this one here on SO](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/2188659/stock-icons-not-shown-on-buttons). However, neither of them provide explanations/solutions for why this is happening this way in Glade, just programmatic solutions.

Does anyone know why this is/how to make the icons show up in the preview?

Answer (score 1):

The proper way to use custom icons is to install them into the icons folder (system being */usr/share/icons/hicolor/**) and then always reference your icon by icon-name which GtkImage takes. What is happening here is likely a path issue where glade is trying to look for the file and cannot find it which of course would not happen when the standard paths are used.

Answer (score 1):

What version of Glade are you using? You might have run into this pre-3.18 bug (https://bugzilla.gnome.org/show_bug.cgi?id=727914). In any case you should try to build the newest version of Glade using JHBuild (https://developer.gnome.org/jhbuild/stable/getting-started.html). That way you always have access to the newest widgets.